# VHF radio - Motorola GM340 - could I have damaged it with too much current? Why would it not be damaged by being connected to a 12v battery?

Tags: dc, ham-radio, vhf

I connected a Motorola GM340 VHF radio to the 12v DC converter for another radio, an ICOM IC78, which gives 13.7v at 16 amps. The wiring did not have a fuse. As it did not work, I wonder if the current was too high and I have damaged it, but if so: how come it can be connected straight to a 12v car battery? Would the current not also be too high? I presume I am misunderstanding something.

Service manual and specs:

http://www.condord.com/lmr/motorola/MOTOROLA%205%20TONE/MOBILES/Service%20Manual/GM300_SM.PDF
http://www.motorolasolutions.com/XU-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Two-Way+Radios+-+Licensed/Mobile+Radios/GM+Professional+Series/GM340_XU-EN,PK-EN

Comment: Does it still work in the car? Did it before you did this test?

Answer (score 1):

As with any load connected to a voltage source, that load takes ONLY the current that it requires and this is governed by its electrical resistance. If your radio took 1 amp from a 12 volt supply it's because it has a resistance of 12 ohm - this is ohms law.

If a power supply is 12 volts and capable of supplying 1 million amps, "your radio" will still only take 1 amp. When you connected it to 13.7 volts it might have taken 1.14 amps and if it's still working you can presume that it is likely to be OK.

Comment: So then what is the use of a fuse in a wire? I thought this was to protect the device from too much current - 15 amp fuse, 30 amp fuse etc. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: A fuse is to prevent fires due to cables melting - anyone designing a fuse into their equipment usually does so for this reason alone. I'm sure there may be exceptions of course.

Comment: A VHF radio isn't really a purely resistive load, so suggesting that it draws a certain current "because it has a resistance" is slightly disingenuous. Most modern electronics have switching DC DC converters within them which will actually result in a lower current draw when the supply is at a higher voltage.

Comment: @LeoR Yes I know that but to get my point over I simplified the thinking process so the OP could acclimatise themselves with ohms law rather than jumping in at what would be undoubtedly the deep end but thanks for your contribution. Just to be clear, a VHF radio doesn't have to have a switcher on-board and could be purely linear and, for the most part would look like a resistor (give or take a few nuances) from a few volts up to over its nominal supply voltage.